# How can I change the default downloading folder for Transmission?

Tags: transmission

I would like to change the folder but I don't know where can I configure Tranmission.

Answer (score 11):

Open transmission ----->

Click **Edit** ------> **preferences** -------> **Downloading** .

[image]

You can see **Save to location** , change it to the **path you want**.

Answer (score 5):

And if you're using Transmission from the web located at `http://localhost:9091`.

Click on the wrench at the bottom-left of the page:

[image]

Then set the **Download to:** field to the desired location. This will be the default location:

[image].

And in case you have torrent(s) who's location you want to change. Then right-click on any one of the torrent(s) in the list and select **Set Location...**

[image]

and then set the location to wherever you want it

[image]

all the existing data belonging to that torrent will be moved to that location.

Answer (score 2):

Open  Transmission  ----> edit ----> preferences

This opens a new window and then you go to the downloading tab and you can change where transmission downloads to.

Answer (score 0):

Open Edit --- > Preferences then click the Downloading option. There will be you have Location option change your location.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `download-dir` via `transmission-remote` command, e.g.

```
transmission-remote -w ~/Downloads/_Transmission
```

<sup>Note: If you've authentication enabled, add: `--auth username:password`, otherwise disable [RPC authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18936994/55075).</sup>

To change incomplete directory, run e.g.:

```
transmission-remote -c "$HOME"/Downloads/_Transmission/_Temp
```

Or you can edit user's settings in `~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json`:

```
$ grep dir ~/.config/transmission-daemon/settings.json
    "download-dir": "/home/kenorb/Downloads",
    "incomplete-dir": "/home/kenorb/Downloads",
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": false,
```

For global settings, see: `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`

To dump the current settings, run:

```
transmission-daemon --dump-settings
```

To reload service, run:

```
sudo invoke-rc.d transmission-daemon reload
```

To restart service (this will override global `settings.json`), run:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon restart
```

See also:

- [Transmission- HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TransmissionHowTo).
- [Transmission wiki page at archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Transmission).
- [Transmission's wiki at GitHub](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki).

Comment: `transmission-remote -w ~/Downloads/_Transmission`
Will only update the default setting but not the configured directory for existing torrents. (At least for my Transmission 3.0.0 bb6b5a062e)